# Pass boolean argument by reference

Tags: python

In C++ you can always pass something as reference and anything that happens within the callee would be known to caller by just examining the referenced variable.

Imagine this scenario:

```
def x():
   a = f()
   print(a)

def f():
   return "hello"
```

What I want is add a boolean flag that returns from f to x. There are several ways to do that:

1. make f return a tuple (str,bool)
2. pass a reference to a boolean variable into f

option 1 is currently not possible since there are many callers to f() and I cant change them to accept tuple as return value, so it must stay as it is.

option 2 is not possible since boolean argument is immutable (as I've learned recently).

Only f can calculate the boolean value, and x needs to know about it.

Is there any good way to achieve that? Looking for something that is not bad practice in Python coding in general.

Comment: What is the Boolean flag for?

Comment: You can pass in a list of bools and modify the element of the list directly.  e.g. b[0]=True where you passed list b into the function.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you cant change caller to accept tuple as value?

Comment: Especially since you'd have to change all the callers to pass the Boolean flag reference you're proposing.

Comment: I think many of these would be answered if we had a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please don't [re-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72467392/3001761). This still lacks any context as to why you actually want to do this, which means it's impossible to say what the right answer actually is.

Comment: I think you might rethink all the code, but you could patch it (not recommended... ) pass a list with the flag `[flag]` then the list will mutate

Comment: @FredLarson I can just pass an argument with None default value, so other callers wont notice the change.

there are many callers expecting an ORM object return value,
if I return (ORM object,bool) value, would they work the same? 
I cant change them to accept something else beside ORM object

Comment: You could also put all your functions inside a class and use `self.flag = True` to set the flag without having to return anything. This would also be accessible to all methods within the class

Comment: >{looking for something that is no bad practice in python coding in general} The idiomatic ("Pythonic") way would be to change the function to return a tuple. If the function is prone to changing the things that it returns and you don't want to break callers, maybe consider returning a record (like a `dataclass`) - something like a Parameter Object, but for a return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option that's closest to passing a pointer/reference into `f` would be to pass it a mutable object, like a list:

```
def f(ok=None):
    if isinstance(ok, list):
        ok.append(True)
    return "hello"

def x():
    ok = []
    a = f(ok)
    print(a, ok.pop())
```

But the better solution IMO would be to return a tuple, and refactor that behavior into a new function so that you're sharing code without disturbing the existing API:

```
def f_with_flag():
    return "hello", True

def f():
    return f_with_flag()[0]

def x():
    a, ok = f_with_flag()
    print(a, ok)
```

Comment: +1 for the second approach (maybe replace index access with tuple unpacking?). Lets you both stay idiomatic and keep backwards compatibility.

Comment: second solution is awesome, this is why I get into python.
thanks!